# Sql Server Entity in H2 Schema Not Found

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-data, h2

Tests are already written that used Sql Server and worked but I am going back and trying with H2 just to speed things up. The entity is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Rules"
        ,schema="dbo"
        ,catalog="ABM"
)
public class Rules {
....
}
```

which was generated for me with reverse engineering against Sql Server and I intend to have test using H2 with that entity.
However I get:

```
 Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "ABM" not found; SQL statement:
```

with show sql set to true I see:

```
... from abm.dbo.rules ....
```

H2 must not know what 'abm' is. Looking into creating a schema I updating the url to this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ABM;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA ABM;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;USE SCHEMA ABM
```

Still having the same problem. Can I use an entity created for Sql Server with catalog set to something in H2?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

How I got around this was that the entity has catalog and schema and for H2 there really isn't the concept of catalogs. Catalogs are basically just database and you can create schemas so I did this:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "h2soruce")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabase build = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("ABM").addScript("init.sql").build();
    return build;
}
```

and under resources init.sql had this

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbo;
```

found that on github: demo-spring-data-jpa-hibernate-h2